# loading excel data from sharepoint library to table using ssis

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have created a library in sharepoint.Inside the library I created sharepoint default columns like doctype,filename,modified,modifiedby,status.

In filename column I have excel doc present.I want to load the excel data from this library to a table using SSIS Package.The number of columns in excel is same as table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load data from Sharepoint, I'll recommend you to use the [Odata Source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42280)

Then with the absolute path to the xls, you can use an Excel Source to load your data to a table